# Is there any way to disable Proguard configuration output?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-r8

I use this in each module of my multi-module library project

```
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), '../proguard-rules-library.pro'
```

Is there any way I can disable configuration outputs to console on build stage? This is an example:

```
The proguard configuration file for the following section is C:\Users\pc\Development\project\build\app\intermediates\default_proguard_files\global\proguard-android.txt-7.2.2
This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
```

This is just a part of a log output. It goes on further with printing the contents of my proguard-rules-library.pro files

P.S. there is no -printconfiguration flag in the file, but default proguard-android-optimize has the -verbose flag. But I don't think it could be the cause of such behavior

Comment: I hope you are looking to disable logs output while using Proguard?

Comment: I'm looking to, let's say, run the proguard in silent mode. Because right now the proguard behaves like there is a printconfiguration flag on. It basically prints all lines of the proguard-rules.pro. And that's what I'm trying to disable

Answer (score 0):

You can remove logging calls with this option in `proguard-project.txt`:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { 
  public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
  public static int v(...);
  public static int i(...);
  public static int w(...);
  public static int d(...);
  public static int e(...);
}
```

This option is relevant if optimization is not disabled, like in `proguard-android.txt`. You have to specify `proguard-android-optimize.txt` instead, in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: >-assumenosideeffects
Does it affect the building phase proguard logs? Or the runtime logs?